# Insert Text Into Tumblr Ask Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

Does anyone know if there's a way to ***add text*** into the ***tumblr ask box*** when the page is first loaded? I'm running a blog where people can ask for advice from either a girl or a guy. I want them to click a link and go to the ask page but then depending on the link they clicked, ***#AskHim or #AskHer will be pre-added into the ask box***. Without these "tags" (just basic text), all questions come to my inbox and I have no idea what perspective (guy or girl) they want their question answered from.

HTML:

```
<div id="askbox">
   <iframe frameborder="0" height="190" id="ask_form" scrolling="no" 
   src="http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/whatishethinking.tumblr.com"
   width="100%" style="background-color: transparent; overflow: hidden;"
   </iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#askbox {
   margin: 10px auto;
   width:600px;
}
```

I've found topics on how to insert text into a text box using javascript. However, tumblr has it's own built in tagging/html system so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

i.e.

```
<script>
   function add(text){
      var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("Mytextbox");
      TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + text;
   }
</script>
```

Also, here is a link to my blog ([Main Blog](http://whatishethinking.tumblr.com)). The user will click either the "Ask Her" or "Ask Him" image links on the left side of my blog.

[image: links on my blog]

Then this will take them to my ask page where I want the text to be inserted into the ask box ([Ask Page](http://whatishethinking.tumblr.com/askaway)).

[image: example of text added to ask box]

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of achieving this off the top of my head is by using the [placeholder attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_placeholder).

However, I'm not sure you'd be able to manipulate the main text area, since Tumblr utilizes iframes for customized ask pages.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I can write a javascript function for it or not. If you can think of anything else, please let me know.

Comment: @TheUnCola You have a couple of issues here. Firstly it does appear as the source of the iframe for the ask form is on the same domain as your tumblr account (I believe so anyway) http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/whatishethinking.tumblr.com if it is on the same domain, you should be able to target it using jquery (it will be possible in javascript, but my pure js skills are lacking). The other issue you have is that if you want to target these iframes separately they both currently have the same id. It should still be possible to target them as they appear to have unique parent wrappers.

Comment: @TheUnCola if you think this might help I can try and write some code for you to test out.

Comment: @TheUnCola also there is already an error on the page you linked to in the console, you may have to fix that before you can get other custom js to run.

Comment: Actually you may have to scrap this, I think the main domain might be the same, but your tumblr will be on a different subdomain, so I don't think this will work. Sorry.

Comment: @Iharby So the verdict is that it won't work at all? Also, what error are you talking about?

Comment: @Vincent I got the placeholder text to work with a bit of effort. You can see it by going to the ask link I provided. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: YW. I can see how it might be possible playing around with divs